# UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Keyboard" keeps reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, custom-keyboard

I am creating a custom keyboard that recreates the number and decimal keyboard, which is required for app submission. Currently I am using the method:

```
if ([self isOpenAccessGranted] == false)  {
} else {
}
```

to check whether or not the user has allowed full access. When I try to load my storyboard file (`Keyboard.storyboard`) with the following method:

```
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Keyboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"KeyboardViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The `storyboard` file just keeps refreshing in my custom keyboard view and functionality for the keyboard does not work. I labeled it with a storyboard id (`KeyboardViewController`) and checked the `storyboardID` button.

It is note worthing that when `isOpenAccessGrantred` is set to true, it loads a programmatically created `UICollectionview` Keyboard built using a collection frame. I have a suspicion this is what's causing it but not entirely sure.

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i am calling the '[UIStoryboard storyboardWirthName:@"Keyboard" bundle:nil]' method inside of 'viewDidAppear'...i think this might have something to do with it as well..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

If you are using a `Storyboard` file with `Custom Keyboard` make sure to edit your `p-list` to add the following:

```
NSExtensionMainStoryboard -> String -> Keyboard
```

and delete the following:

```
NSExtensionPrincipalClass -> KeyboardViewController
```